# Queues Dispatch method in Laravel Throws error

Tags: laravel-5, jobs

So this is my line of code

```
public function getVisitedCountriesCountAttribute()
{
    $this->dispatch(new CalculateTotalCountriesVisited($this));

    return $this->total_countries;
}
```

here the dispatch method throws an error saying

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dispatch() (View: /Users/mereeva/sites/rdb-ws/resources/views/users/trips/status.blade.php)
```

I don't seem to understand what could be the reason behind this. i followed all the steps in https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to dispatch from your model you have to use the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;` in it, otherwise you won't be able to do `$this->dispatch(...`.

Another way without using this trait would be to use the dispatch helper:

`dispatch(new CalculateTotalCountriesVisited($this));`

Which would automatically resolve a Dispatcher from the app container.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Dint realise I was using it in the model. Thank you so much